# Why does ubuntu gives me error when i try to insatll pycharm?

Tags: python, ubuntu, pycharm

I downloaded pycharm community version for my windows and to install it I go through Commands in my terminal:-

1. cd Downloads
   2.cd PycharmCommunity-2018.3.4
   3.cd bin
   4.sh pycharm.sh

but whener i run the last command it shows this error

No JDK found. Please validate either PYCHARM_JDK, JDK_HOME or JAVA_HOME environment variable points to valid JDK installation.

but i am using it for python, what would be the solution for this problem. I have already installed python3 in my ubuntu. Help me to resolve this problem as i am new in ubuntu

Comment: Have you tried following this?
https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-pycharm-on-ubuntu-18-04/

I know that you install Pycharm for python, but Pycharm itself needs Java to run the program tho

Comment: do you hava java installed in your system if installed then add it java to the `PATH`

Comment: Wrong place - this is not a programming issue, it's a program installation one.  And googling for your error message yields a lot of results...

Comment: Try with the latest PyCharm from https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/, it has Java Runtime Environment bundled